# PrimeFaces page update after async thread finish job

Tags: multithreading, primefaces

I've tried to write some online calendar generator which generates print ready PDF calendars based on user images. The problem is that generating preview of this calendar is taking a lot of time, mainly since it's done in a different thread.
The pages looks like:

- Page one: image uploading
- Page two: summary and calendar preview

The preview starts to generate after images are uploaded on page one and can take 15-20 sec. By that time, the user can go to page two, where the "preview is being prepared" message is displayed.

I'm using the callback mechanism to access session scoped bean to update item on page two, unfortunately when I trying to get RequestContext or FacesContext.getPartialViewContext() I get a null pointer exception.

The question is: is there any way to solve that and update page component after the thread finises it's job?

Comment: You can implement a tight polling or interval polling to "push" to client.

Comment: yes that should work, that is not the solution that I'd liked, but it is one that should work. Thanks!